# Unauthorized error while configuring two Security Configurations

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-rest

I am working with two Security configuration by extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdaptor` like below

```
@Configuration
@Order(100)
public class CustomerSecurityAppConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user1")
                .password("{noop}password")
                .and()
                .withUser("user2")
                .password("{noop}password")
                
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors().disable();

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/customers/**")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}

@Configuration
class EmployeeSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin")
                .password("{noop}password")
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
                .and()
                .withUser("user")
                .password("{noop}password")
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors().disable();

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/inventory/**")
                .hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/inventory/**")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

The idea here is to have two `realms`. One for customers and one for orders. When I make the HTTP requests, I am getting `200 OK` response for both the `/inventory` and `/customers` endpoint with the users configured for `CustomerSecurityConfiguration` and getting `401` error for both users configured for `EmployeeSecurityConfiguration` configuration. I have two REST endpoints for `inventory` and `customers` with `GET` and `POST`.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You may check the source code of spring implementation behind `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` build-up, multiple configurations may not be merged, instead, they may be covered. Like the second loaded one covers the first one. Did you set a breakpoint at each config class? I guess `EmployeeSecurityConfiguration` is not working, because it is loaded before `CustomerSecurityConfiguration`

Comment: @Tiina I was able to figure out. Both security filter chain have to be configured with the `RequestMatcher` else the default is `Requestmatcher` with `any`. We need to create separate security filter chain for different domains.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the request matcher for the http like below

```
    http
       .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/actuator/**")
       .and()
       .authorizeRequests()
       .anyRequest()
       .authenticated()
       .and()
       .formLogin()
       .and()
       .httpBasic();
```